# How to use/insert a generated random number?

Tags: python, random, vpython

I generate a number in the range 1 to 100. This number should be in the first coordinate of the `pos = vec(0,0,0)` (so on the x-axis). The other axes should stay 0. How can I transfer the generated number to this point?

```
from vpython import*
from random import randint



#Sonne
sun = sphere(pos = vec(0,0,0), radius = 9, make_trail = True ) 
sun.mass = 2e30   
sun.velocity = vec(0,0,0)

#Merkur
mercury_pos_x = randint(1, 100)
mercury = sphere(pos = vec(mercury_pos_x,0,0), radius = 5, color=color.red, make_trail = True ) 
mercury.mass = 3.25e23
mercury.velocity = vec(0,0,-47000)

#Venus
venus_pos_x = randint(1, 100)
venus = sphere(pos = vec(venus_pos_x,0,0), radius = 6, color=color.cyan, make_trail = True ) 
venus.mass = 4.9e24
venus.velocity = vec(0,0,-35000)
```

Comment: Do you want *one* random value used for each of the bodies, or a separate value for each body?  Does the Sun remain at (0,0,0)?

Comment: @Prune a separate. The sun yes. But I actually would have 9 planets and the sun. This is just an excerpt. So one value for every planet on the x axis

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you want a different random start for each planet, leaving the Sun at (0,0,0).  For two random numbers, you need to call `random` twice, keeping the value each time for later use.

```
merc_pos = randint(1, 100)
mercury = sphere(pos = vec(merc_pos,0,0), radius = s_rad1/2,
                 color=color.red, make_trail = True ) 

venus_pos = randint(1, 100)
venus = sphere(pos = vec(venus_pos,0,0), radius = s_rad1/1.8,
               color=color.cyan, make_trail = True )
```

If you're not going to use the random value elsewhere, you can plug it in place:

```
mercury = sphere(pos = vec(randint(1, 100),0,0), radius = s_rad1/2,
                 color=color.red, make_trail = True )
```

Comment: thank you I was looking for smth like that. The only problem I have now is that after 0.5 seconds the simulation is breaking down and the window just quits(when debugging) When I start without debugging it says "ImportError: cannot import name 'randint'". should I import another package? I renewed the code in the question with your solution.

Comment: Those are unrelated problems.  You should continue to import `randint` just as you always have.  If you can't manage to find the problem with incremental changes to your original code and on-line searches, then you should post a separate question.  That question would include the code to reproduce the problem.  Since neither of those conditions appears here, I can't really help you any more.